# How do you get the list of accounts from Analytics using php client libarary

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I'm having a range of problems finding documentation that is correct for the Google Analytics API when using the php client,

I Found: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api#query_profile

But it's just wrong...

```
$analytics = new \Google_Service_Analytics($cleint);
$analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
```

Just results in

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method
>   Google_Service_Analytics_ManagementAccountSummaries_Resource::listManagementAccounts()

i can't find out how in hells name im supposed to get a list of the accounts the logged in user has access to.

And Google seems to provide loads of documentation but none of it correct. can some one tell me how i fix this and even better where documentation that is correct is hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Hello Analytics API docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/service-php) have been recently updated. But it could be that you are using an out of date client library. You can get the latest [client libraries](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) from github.

You can see the [ListManagementAccountSummaries](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Analytics.php#L2146) defined in the source code.